# Transferring SumProduct function into VBA

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I'm trying to write a code contains the following line:

```
WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((Columns(3) = ActiveCell.Value) + 0)
```

The code always returns a Type mismatch error!

I'm using that line of code to avoid using Countif function with more than 255 length string.

Thanks in advance

This is the original Code:

```
Dim MyColumn As Long, r As Long, lngLastRow As Long
MyColumn = ActiveCell.Column
With Sheets("Project Breakdown")
lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, MyColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = lngLastRow To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Cells(r, MyColumn - 2), "DIV", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, Cells(r, MyColumn - 2), "SEC", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
             If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(MyColumn), .Cells(r, MyColumn).Value) > 1 Then
            .Cells(r, MyColumn).Delete Shift:=xlUp
             End If
        End If
    Next r
End With
```

The countif returns an error as the string exceeds 255 in length so I tried useing the sumproduct function instead but can't get it to work.

Comment: Did you check other counting functions (e.g. COUNTA)?

Comment: you want to mutiply the values in Column C with what ? what column or Range ?

Comment: Please see the update. thanks

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to achieve with your code ? maybe you don't need either of the functions

Comment: @ShaiRado ok. I'm trying to make a code to remove duplicated in column C but with conditions based on Column A that the code deletes the duplicates in C as long as the column A does not contain either words "DIV" or "SEC". It works very well but when the string goes over 255 in length an error occur :(

Comment: @user7390329 you could use the `AutoFilter` to hide all of the rows with "DIV" or "SEC" in Column A, and then just use `RemoveDuplicates` from Column C (use the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to define a new range of the filterred rows)

Comment: @ShaiRado I tried doing that before but I figured that remove duplicates also removes non-filtered rows. Could you be more specific about the (xlCellTypeVisible). VBA was hieroglyphs to me couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you compare a Range with a single value. 
This works in an excel formula but not in vba.

One workaround would be to use an extra column in your sheet e.g.

```
=if($C1='some value',1,0)
```

and then take the sum of this column.

Alternatively you could calculate the sumproduct in excel. Write the value of the active cell in a predefined cell (e.g. A1), and have your sumproduct use this formula:

```
=sumproduct((C:C=$A$1)+0)
```

Update:
Assuming A1 is a free cell and A2 contains the following formula:

```
=SumProduct((C:C=$A$1)+0)
```

By changing the value of A1 to your current cell this formula contains your result.

```
Dim MyColumn As Long, r As Long, lngLastRow As Long
MyColumn = ActiveCell.Column
With Sheets("Project Breakdown")
lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, MyColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = lngLastRow To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Cells(r, MyColumn - 2), "DIV", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, Cells(r, MyColumn - 2), "SEC", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
             .cells(1,1).value = .cells(r, MyColumn).value
             ' Might be necessary to call .Calculate here to assure that A2 contains its new value
             If .cells(1,2) > 1 Then
            .Cells(r, MyColumn).Delete Shift:=xlUp
             End If
        End If
    Next r
End With
```

Comment: I'm very sorry but I still can't understand how the information you said would help me get the line code to perform as desired. Please review the update in the original post as I can't make the activecell fixed. It does changes in the for next loop!

Comment: Well, it does work but it takes significant amount of time to finish :( .. is there any other way around or maybe the right syntax for the SumProduct to perform properly

Comment: If you only need to know whether there is an occurence, you can use the Range.find method.
if not .columns(3).find(ActiveCell.value) is nothing ...